# Graph theory algorithm - optimizing arrangement of right-angle arrows for graphical interface in workflow

Tags: c++, user-interface, graph, workflow, graph-theory

I am working on a software with a graphical interface in workflow mode that accept drag and drop of widgets, and creation of arrows between modules, to show where the data come from, and where they go.

Current challenge is to implement automatic arrangement of arrows: when an arrow is drawn, it should be right angle and avoid all other widgets, and also avoid crossing other arrows as much as possible. I assume an algorithm for minimal path finding in graph theory could be useful.

All that is implemented with C++ / Qt.

Did you face same issue, and do you have an more precise idea regarding a suitable algorithm?

Could you hint at some beneficial reference?

thanks and regards

Comment: [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is state of the art for graph layouting. You can get much inspiration there, and there is a libgraphviz for inclusion in other software.

Comment: @thiton  Thanks a lot! do you know something about kind of licence (asking even if I will do own research)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very intresting problem...i think the most easily applicable (and fun) method is:
Fruchterman: graph drawing by force directred placement

Comment: Fruchterman proposes algo so that some edges are arranged observing this: 'It guarantees that topologically near nodes are placed in the same vicinity, and far nodes are placed far from each other.'. However, I am looking for algorihtm s.t. edges are becoming right angle in order to minimize crossing and avoid other graphical structures. for the right angle problem in particular, do you have some idea? Thanks.